# Condition making a relation reflexive

Tags: discrete-mathematics, relations

The relation R = {(a, b) ∣ a = b or a = −b} [a, b ∈ Z] is reflexive, as per `Discrete Mathematics and Its Applications 8th Edition by Kenneth Rosen`.

Is this because `a = b` short-circuits the evaluation of `a = b or a = −b` (making it always true), or is there some other reason why the relation is reflexive?

Comment: It's because every number is equal to itself.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "short-circuits".  A relation $R$ is reflexive precisely when $(a,a) \in R$ for every $a$.  The relation which you have given is $$ R = \{ (a,b) : a = b \text{ or } a=-b \}. $$
I interpret this to mean that
$$ R = \{ (a,a) : a \in \mathbb{Z} \} \cup \{ (a,-a) : a \in \mathbb{Z} \}. $$
The first term in this union is precisely what is required for a relation to be reflexive.

Comment: Yes, you can think of this as a logical short-circuit: $a = a$ is trivially true, so the other term in the or doesn't matter

Answer (score 1):

To see reflexivity, note that "$a=a$ or $a=-a$" is always true, because of the first bit - either one of these statements needs to be true, after all, not both. So you could think of the first statement as "short-circuiting" the reflexivity statement, since that $a=-a$ statement is not necessary for it.

If it makes you more comfortable, perhaps think of $R$ as being all $(a,b)$ for $a,b \in \Bbb Z$ where $|a|=|b|$,